# How to change the style of the deep view html page in branch.io ? (Create a custom style)

Tags: html, ios, css, branch.io

I am unable to create a custom deep view for ios. Every change is saved and registered except the change to the style of the deepview. For example ,say i add fonts-style under the style tag to my deep view html page:

```
    <style>
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'montserrat';
    src: url('montserrat-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('montserrat-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: regular;
    font-style: normal;
    }
    </style>
```

(I have a lot of code to be added to the style part and am stating this just as an example.) So basically when i write this in the deep view html window provided by branch.io the changes are seen on the preview window but as soon as i hit 'save' the page refreshes and i lose my changes. Any suggestion as to what i'm missing here, or how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex from Branch here: I am able to duplicate this issue — definitely looks like a bug, so I'll make sure it gets filed for attention.

In the meantime, I was able to update the style content by doing the following steps:

1. Remove ALL code from the Deepview template (save it somewhere else temporarily)
2. Save template. It will be blank
3. Put all code back into the template and save again
4. Now you can update the style block and it will save successfully

Comment: I tried it, but it still doesn't work. No matter what i do, the changes that i make under style, (adding the css to the same page) does not get saved.

Comment: Can you post a sample link from your application?

Comment: I found out the problem. I am unable to import anything from the local database or from the net. So basically none of the imports or the link tags are working.

Comment: Ahhh. Yes, we sanitize things like that for security. If you want something more custom, you could host your own content and use our web-to-app feature to basically create a deep view that is totally under your control!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by putting the font-face to an external css file and using link tag to import it to the deepview.

```
    <link href="https://my-own-server.com/deepviews.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome instead.

When I did this, using Safari, the edits would not save.

I switched to using Chrome and now my edits saved.